# Extract recurring characters conditional on a binary variable

Tags: r, string, identifier, recurrence

I have a list of url strings and for each url a human coded binary variable indicates whether it is an affiliate url (or not).

I want to understand...
(1) which combination of characters is recurring/mostly repeated in the affiliate urls, and
(2) which combination of characters identified in 1. does (mostly) not occur in the non-affiliate urls.

The ultimate goal is to automatically detect whether an url is affiliate (or not) because I need to code the binary variable for thousands of urls.

A dataframe of 20 affiliate urls:

```
da_affiliate = data.frame(url = c("https://www.connox.de/kategorien/leuchten/tischleuchten/menu-reverse-tischleuchte.html?utm_source=www.mydealz.de&utm_campaign=idealo", 
                        "https://mydealz.digidip.net/visit?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbeoprime.com%2FBeosound-Stage-1008648%3Fchannable%3De75591.MTAwODY0OA%26number%3D1008647&ppref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydealz.de&ref=1653552281", 
                        "https://de.aliexpress.com/item/4000941962566.html?dp=11003b5tjna0&aff_fcid=5528200812e34a8cbe97e86718c29519-1676649257687-03641-NUUJNoAU&aff_fsk=NUUJNoAU&aff_platform=promotion&sk=NUUJNoAU&aff_trace_key=5528200812e34a8cbe97e86718c29519-1676649257687-03641-NUUJNoAU&terminal_id=2a3c660edc804f308db608849cb0adb2&afSmartRedirect=y&gatewayAdapt=glo2deu", 
                        "https://t.adcell.com/forward?promoId=66704&slotId=57715&subId=11003b5tjnhh&param0=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dealclub.de%2Fshop%2Fmode-accessoires%2F12er-pack-herren-unterhosen-boxershorts-gr-s-m-l-xl-xxl-baumwolle%2F&referer=", 
                        "https://t.adcell.com/forward?promoId=114552&slotId=57715&subId=11003b5tjnkl&param0=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.blumeideal.de%2Fpfingstrosen-coral-sunset.html&referer=", 
                        "https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/1-74-hi-index-asperic-uv400_204289704.html?spm=a2700.icbuShop.41413.11.520f56fautdiSj&fullFirstScreen=true&bypass=true&bm=cps&src=saf&pid=269979&tp1=17943_1676649294_2c2b94e4b4bb4688450c39361d07b3c3&awc=17943_1676649294_2c2b94e4b4bb4688450c39361d07b3c3", 
                        "https://ww44.affinity.net/sssweb?enk=2b5e3683bbb87899d926c7815388849cb0256510c5ffcaa74543fc962edb2e0aa509cf83ffc4f22630229dc3d8ae34136d34864af9c131bf54fbaf5c7e2085ee&di=13003b1p039b&subid=mydealz.de&cc=DE&d=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.manomano.de%2Fp%2Fkaercher-multifunktions-spritzpistolenset-plus-1583275%3Freferer_id%3D668893", 
                        "https://www.zavvi.de/collections/terror.list?affil=awin&utm_content=digidip&utm_term=Sub+Networks&utm_source=AWin-269979&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=AffiliateWin&sv1=affiliate&sv_campaign_id=269979&awc=10547_1676649339_5657338530d8d9da570464d8f639aa4d", 
                        "https://www.zavvi.de/kleidung/angebote/kids.list?affil=awin&utm_content=digidip&utm_term=Sub+Networks&utm_source=AWin-269979&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=AffiliateWin&sv1=affiliate&sv_campaign_id=269979&awc=10547_1676649345_0748ef6a02b61d35c419652054264d80", 
                        "https://www.zavvi.de/kleidung/angebote/2-for-18.list?pageNumber=1&affil=awin&utm_content=digidip&utm_term=Sub+Networks&utm_source=AWin-269979&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=AffiliateWin&sv1=affiliate&sv_campaign_id=269979&awc=10547_1676649357_396bf29d32388d9fb3091d43f242081f", 
                        "https://www.eleonto.com/de-DE/brands/libratone/libratone-zipp-2-multiroom-speaker/p/247284?wt_mc=paid.affiliate.awin.eleonto..pub269979.ad&wt_cc3=269979&wt_cc4=standard%20&awc=18832_1676649369_944feb3c1da4e1673a6c40f7b63ef61d", 
                        "https://www.mypopupclub.de/search/?query=torwarthandschuh&items=40&awc=24647_1676649398_b50eec92d02713cb93041074ea87f035", 
                        "https://www.kaufland.de?utm_source=mydealz&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=pricecomparison&utm_term=1653553805", 
                        "https://www.baywa.de/de/haus-hof/salze/wasserenthaertung/sws-broxo-6--15-regeneriersalz-fuer-ionenaustauschersysteme-/p-000000000000648647/?utm_source=awin&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_term=269979&utm_content=digidip.net&awc=26219_1676649431_f1c351b9429bcaaddaffe2343fd7e85d", 
                        "https://www.peek-cloppenburg.de?utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=awin_269979&utm_term=subnetwork&awc=14716_1676649443_ce0033a5ed9fdebf56193e07271de6c6", 
                        "https://de.jbl.com/bluetooth-lautsprecher/JBLFLIPESSENTIAL.html?utm_source=tradetracker&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=de&utm_content=Digidip&utm_term=%28Sub%29Network", 
                        "https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07RFL2XM7?tag=pepperugc09-21&ascsubtag=1653554179", 
                        "https://www.moemax.de/p/bessagi-home-hocker-in-grau-havan-001078003802?utm_source=easymarketing-Digidip&utm_medium=private-network&utm_campaign=n_sl_prvt-netwrk_ao_on_mmx-de&utm_content=mmx-de_conversion_n_Deals_n&utm_term=390843-50050&emid=63efa3fd60e1ec01e93e3805&awin_id=NULL&ia-pkpmtrack=100-5363735313236323131303-368-101-101", 
                        "https://www.moemax.de/p/clatronic-smoothie-maker-clatronic-004547014801?utm_source=easymarketing-Digidip&utm_medium=private-network&utm_campaign=n_sl_prvt-netwrk_ao_on_mmx-de&utm_content=mmx-de_conversion_n_Deals_n&utm_term=390843-50050&emid=63efa40260e1ec01e93e380b&awin_id=NULL&ia-pkpmtrack=100-5363735313236323131303-368-101-101", 
                        "https://www.ibood.com/diy-de/de/product-specs/61192/289955/2x-gardena-comfort-gartenschere.html?wgu=284375_116019_16766494808318_45f222a42e&wgexpiry=1708185480&utm_source=digidip%20GmbH&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=webgains_de"),
                        affiliate = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

A dataframe of 20 non-affiliate urls:

```
da_affiliate_no = data.frame(url = c("https://www.cdkeys.com/xbox-live/memberships/12-month-xbox-live-gold-membership-xbox-one-360-brazil", 
                                     "https://sonstnix.de/Corratec-E-Corones-Elite-E-Rennrad", "https://www.manfrotto.com/de-de/manfrotto-syrp-evolution/", 
                                     "https://frostkauf.de/frostkauf-vor-ort", "https://frostkauf.de/frostkauf-vor-ort", 
                                     "https://www.galeria.de/Emsa-Isolierbecher-Travel-Mug-mit-Manschette-0-36-Liter/33779970.html", 
                                     "https://www.netcup.de/bestellen/produkt.php?produkt=2058", "https://www.loow.com/collections/womens", 
                                     "https://www.koffer-direkt.de/?ra_id=2267119337", "https://www.hhv.de/shop/de/hhv-clothing-sale/p:6IHHzs", 
                                     "https://www.galeria.de/RALPH-LAUREN-Ultra-Blue-EdT/34273922.html", 
                                     "https://www.mindfactory.de/Highlights/MindStar", "https://www.padi.com/de/tauchen/elearning-angebot", 
                                     "https://www.tara-m.de", "https://www.saturn.de/de/product/_amazon-echo-dot-3-generation-mit-alexa-2602388.html", 
                                     "https://www.saturn.de/de/product/_sandisk-ultra%C2%AE-2363794.html", 
                                     "https://www.aldi-sued.de/de/angebote/frische-kracher-ab-mo-255/detailseite/ps/p/laugenzopf-mit-kaese-7.html", 
                                     "https://www.aldi-sued.de/de/angebote/frische-kracher-ab-mo-204/detailseite/ps/p/laugenzopf-mit-kaese-6.html", 
                                     "https://www.arcido.com/products/faroe", "https://www.3avape.com/vapefly-jestor-pod-kit-1000mah-diy-edition.html"),
                             affiliate = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: An affiliate url almost always has an "affiliate id" simply as they need to track to who the sale belongs. My approach would be to build up a lookup table, with the domain and the parameter they use to identify the affiliate. For example "de.aliexpress.com" uses "aff_fcid" as parameter for the affiliate ID. All those you can assign a "1" for being an affiliate. It will take some time as you need to worry about the "0" values to scan them for new affiliates to grow your lookup table. You can expand it for domains that never can be an affiliate as well, so those "0"'s you do not need to inspect.

Comment: Thanks. This approach would generally work, however, I have thousands of different urls that I need to code (affiliate or not). Therefore, I was looking for an automated way of detecting the affiliate parameters (e.g., aff_fcid).

Comment: I have experience in affiliate marketing and I know there are some using just a "p" to store the affiliate ID, or worse have it in the url (url/12/), while there would be so many other url's around where "p" is used for totally something different. Best bet really is to start blank, grab the domains of all urls, take the count, start inspecting for the paramater used from high to low. Assign 1 if affiliate based on the lookup, assign 0 if you know a domain never can be an affiliate and NA if unsure. From thousands you work your way down to less and less NA's you have to inspect.